# How do i add a barcode to html which will be converted to PDF using DinkToPdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, pdf-generation

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project and on one of the actions I am converting a view to a pdf.

I want to generate a QRBarCode in the html, I found this library https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/tutorials/csharp-barcode-image-generator/ that generates a QRBar code but it only works on .NET and not in .NET Core.

This is how I am converting my view to PDF:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AccreditationLetter(int accreditationId)
{
        //get model
        var htmlContent = View("AccreditationLetter", model).ToHtml(HttpContext);

        var file = await GenerateAccreditationLetter(htmlContent, $"Accreditation Letter");

        return File(file, "application/pdf", "Accreditation Letter.pdf");
}

private async Task<byte[]> GenerateAccreditationLetter(string htmlContent, string title)
{
    var settings = new GlobalSettings
        {
            ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
            Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
            Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 3 },
            DocumentTitle = title
        };

    var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
        {
            PagesCount = true,
            HtmlContent = htmlContent,
            WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8", UserStyleSheet = null }
        };

    var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
        {
            GlobalSettings = settings,
            Objects = { objectSettings }
        };

    return converter.Convert(pdf);
}
```

I need to generate a qrbarcode and add it to the html in the `AccreditationLetter` method. Any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

IronBarcode supports .NET Core 2x & 3x, .NET Standard, and .NET Framework 4x, Full Azure support, as shown on the [Features](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/features/) package on the website.

The [IronBarcode NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BarCode/) shows support for:

- .Net Framework 4.0 +
- .Net Core 2.0 +
- .Net 5
- .Net 6

If you just want a PDF with your barcode, there's no need to use dinkpdf at all - IronBarcode will export to PDF simply using:

```
// Save to a new PDF
MyBarCode.SaveAsPdf("MyBarCode.Pdf");

/// Add the barcode to any page or pages of an existing PDF
MyBarCode.StampToExistingPdfPage("ExistingPDF.pdf", 200, 50, 1);  

// position x=200 y=50 on page 1
MyBarCode.StampToExistingPdfPages("ExistingPDF.pdf", 200, 50, new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, "Password123");  // multiple pages of an encrypted PDF
```

To [export barcodes as HTML](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/examples/export-barcodes-as-html/), this can either be a stand-alone HTML image tag (which can be served in HTML files, ASPX or MVC Views. No image assets required, the tag embeds the entire image in its Src contents)

```
string ImgTag = MyBarCode.ToHtmlTag();
```

Or turn the image into an Html/CSS Data URI.

```
string DataURI = MyBarCode.ToDataUrl();
```